# Dividir uma data em duas parte

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, mysqli

Estou fazendo um calendário usando MySQL, html, JS e PHP.

Esse calendário serve para reservar o salão de festas aqui no prédio.

Pode existir duas reservas no mesmo dia, manhã e tarde que seria "00:00 até 11:59" e "12:00 até 23:59".

**Minha questão:**

Gostaria de uma sugestão para a melhor forma de fazer isso, já pensei em fazer com dois campos `date` e o outro **hora**.

Também imaginei se é possível usar o `datatime`, `timestamp`.

Alguma dica ou sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu armazenaria com 2 campos.

- `data`, campo `date` mesmo (ou `int` a contar numero de dias de uma data padrão).
- `periodo` campo `int` de 1 byte só, ou `enum` sendo:

  - `1` = manhã
  - `2` = tarde
  - `3` = ambos os períodos

Assim simplifica o problema.

### Verificando se a data está livre.

Para testar disponibilidade de data, basta fazer este `select`:

```
SELECT periodo WHERE data=$data AND ( periodo=$periodo OR periodo=3 OR $periodo=3 );
```

- `periodo=$periodo` significa conflito, se pediu manhã e já tem manhâ, ou se pediu tarde e já tem tarde
- `periodo=3` significa conflito, pois se já tem um ocupando o dia todo, não tem como agendar mais nada nessa data.
- `$periodo=3` significa conflito, pois se está tentando agendar dia todo, qualquer agendamento existente impede o agendamento.

Se a *query* acima não retornar nenhum registro, você pode fazer um novo agendamento na data `$data` para o período `$periodo`.

Se, por outro lado, retornar registros, não dá para por o novo agendamento, pois terá um conflito.

Comment: Não a estrutura dessa parte ``( periodo=$periodo OR periodo=3 OR $periodo=3 );``

Comment: Sao os 3 testes que eu expliquei acima.  periodo=$periodo elimina tarde com tarde, e manhã com manha. periodo=3 elimina qualquer agendamento se o dia todo está ocupado. $periodo=3 elimina agendamento para o dia todo, se qualquer outra coisa já existir naquele dia.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma seria usar `datatime`

Para pegar as datas e horas separadamente use:

```
$datetime = '2010-07-05 12:11:00';

list( $date, $time ) = explode( ' ', $datetime );

echo 'Data: '.$date;

echo 'Hora: '.$time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça um campo booleano(no MySQL: bit(1)) em que 0 indica a reserva da manhã e 1 indica a reserva da tarde.

Em relação a data:
Se for por questão facilidade, utilize o o tipo DATE, ele armazena datas no seguinte formato: 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Se for por questão de economia de espaço, crie um campo SMALLINT e armazena o número de dias entre o evento e uma data que você definir, por exemplo, entre 01/01/2015 e o dia do evento e deixa o javascript fazer as contas para transformar isso em data bonita.

Você também pode armazenar tudo no tipo DATETIME, mas acho desnecessário.